# Charset for Platform Event not UTF-8?

Tags: platform-event, character-encoding, base64

When trying to publish a platform event from our middleware solution (Boomi) to our salesforce instance, I'm receiving a 400/Bad request (this was intermittent, as some would process without issue). The only time that this would happen is when the large text field I was feeding a payload string into had a UTF-8 encoded char.

Does anyone know if platform events are default encoded as non-UTF-8?

**Fortunately I'm just going to encode in base64 and then decode within my apex trigger helper class, so it should work okay. I don't like adding to the CPU overhead by doing this, however...

Comment: Strings inside Salesforce are always encoded in UTF-8, but there's definitely some circumstances where the API doesn't interpret incoming data as UTF-8. [Here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/203193/rest-api-unicode-characters-not-working/20331) is one example. Can you tell if any encoding headers are being sent?

Comment: Not to my knowledge, as the "connector" used in Boomi to publish the events aren't super configurable. One of the major drawbacks of using Boomi; there is a lot of data that is configured behind the scenes that you can't access (not just this particular connection type) @David Reed

Comment: everything incoming to SFDC has to be UTF-8 if text; it would be an error on the Boomi side if the text prior to publishing as a platform event is non UTF-8

Comment: @cropredy yeah I think you're right, after debugging a bit more it seems Boomi's default charset for their platform events connector is something other than Unicode. And their isn't any way to change the encoding... not a huge surprise coming from that platform; Boomi has given me tons of little issues like this all over the place.